# Yii2/PostgreSQL - Calling unknown method: yii\db\ActiveQuery::formName()

Tags: php, postgresql, methods, yii2, crud

I'm trying to create a little CRUD application using this tutorial:
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/490/creating-a-simple-crud-app-with-yii2/

Everything but the update and delete function is working. When I click the onto "update", I am getting the following error:

> Calling unknown method: yii\db\ActiveQuery::formName()

When I click onto "delete", I am getting this error:

> Method Not Allowed. This url can only handle the following request
>   methods: POST.

These are my SiteController functions:

```
public function actionDelete($id=NULL)
{
    $model = $this->loadModel($id);

    if (!($model->delete()))
    {
        Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', 'Unable to delete model');
    }

    $this->redirect(\Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl('site/index'));
}

public function actionSave($id=NULL)
{
    if ($id == NULL)
    {
        $model = new Crud;
    } else {
        $model = $this->loadModel($id);
    }

    if(isset($_POST['Crud']))
    {
        $model->load($_POST);

        if ($model->save())
        {
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Model has been saved');
            $this->redirect(['save', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } else {
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', 'Model could not be saved');
        }
    }
    echo $this->render('save',['model' => $model]);
}

private function loadModel($id)
{
    $model = Crud::find($id);

    if ($model == NULL)
    {
        throw new HttpException(404, 'Model not found');
    }

    return $model;
}
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

EDIT: complete error message:

```
exception 'yii\base\InvalidRouteException' with message 'Unable to resolve the request: site/error' in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\basic2\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php:122
Stack trace:
#0 C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\basic2\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php(455): yii\base\Controller->runAction('error', Array)
#1 C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\basic2\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\ErrorHandler.php(79): yii\base\Module->runAction('site/error')
#2 C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\basic2\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\ErrorHandler.php(95): yii\web\ErrorHandler->renderException(Object(yii\web\MethodNotAllowedHttpException))
#3 [internal function]: yii\base\ErrorHandler->handleException(Object(yii\web\MethodNotAllowedHttpException))
#4 {main}
Previous exception:
exception 'yii\web\MethodNotAllowedHttpException' with message 'Method Not Allowed. This url can only handle the following request methods: POST.' in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\basic2\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\filters\VerbFilter.php:105
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: yii\filters\VerbFilter->beforeAction(Object(yii\base\ActionEvent))
#1 C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\basic2\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Component.php(538): call_user_func(Array, Object(yii\base\ActionEvent))
#2 C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\basic2\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php(259): yii\base\Component->trigger('beforeAction', Object(yii\base\ActionEvent))
#3 C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\basic2\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Controller.php(108): yii\base\Controller->beforeAction(Object(yii\base\InlineAction))
#4 C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\basic2\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php(149): yii\web\Controller->beforeAction(Object(yii\base\InlineAction))
#5 C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\basic2\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php(455): yii\base\Controller->runAction('delete', Array)
#6 C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\basic2\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Application.php(83): yii\base\Module->runAction('site/delete', Array)
#7 C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\basic2\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php(375): yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\web\Request))
#8 C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\basic2\web\index.php(12): yii\base\Application->run()
#9 {main}
```

EDIT2: 
My view(save.php) contains the following:

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
?>

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

    <?php echo $form->field($model, 'name')->textInput(array('class' => 'form-control')); ?>
    <?php echo $form->field($model, 'alter')->textInput(array('class' => 'form-control')); ?>

<?php echo Html::submitButton('Senden', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary pull-right')); ?>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

My index.php view contains the following:

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;

$this->title = 'CRUD';
?>


<?php echo Html::a('Neuen Eintrag erstellen', array('site/save'), array('class' => 'btn btn-primary pull-right')); ?>

<div class="clearfix"></div>
<hr />
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Alter</td>
        <td> </td>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach ($models as $post): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo Html::a($post->id, array('site/save', 'id'=>$post->id)); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo Html::a($post->name, array('site/save', 'id'=>$post->id)); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo Html::a($post->alter, array('site/save', 'id'=>$post->id)); ?></td>
            <td>
                <?php echo Html::a('Update', array('site/save', 'id'=>$post->id)); ?>
                <?php echo Html::a('Delete', array('site/delete', 'id'=>$post->id)); ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to delete a record you must fetch it like below:

```
$model = Crud::find($id)->one();
```

So:

```
$model = Crud::find($id)->one()->delete();
```

Or you may use this:

```
protected function findModel($id)
{
    if (($model = Crud::findOne($id)) !== null) {
        return $model;
    } else {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
    }
}
```

Then in action:

```
$model = $this->findModel($id);

if (!($model->delete()))
{
    Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', 'Unable to delete model');
}

$this->redirect(\Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl('site/index'));
```

> Method Not Allowed. This url can only handle the following request methods: POST.

Above error is generally related to the request type, which only `POST` is allowed. To fix that, you must tell Yii2 to handle it like below:

```
<?php echo Html::a('Delete', array('site/delete', 'id'=>$post->id),array('data-method'=>'post')); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you, the message "Method not found" does no longer appear in PhpStorm, but the error from above still appears. I added the complete error message into my first post.

Comment: @Gummikuchen That is because of you don't have `site` controller and `error` action. Make sure that those exist

Comment: Thanks again! First error is fixed, the second erro still occurs:
"Method Not Allowed. This url can only handle the following request methods: POST."

Comment: how do you call this action in view? could you please update your question with the view of delete action? for example if there is a form or there is a link

Comment: I added my 2 view files.

Comment: You are great. The delete button is working :)

Do you also have a solution for my update button? That would totally made my day. :)
"Calling unknown method: yii\db\ActiveQuery::formName()"

Comment: Glad it is working ;) Please change update action with one of solutions in my answer. For example `model->one()` or `findModel($id)`.

Comment: Wow. Could you explain me the difference between my loadModel function and your findModel function? I simply don't understand why this error occured...

Comment: My method, gets only one record from database. But yours, returns a query object. That's all.